# Angular 4: control value is empty when submit a form

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to implement an update form using Angular, the form consist of several controls, I set their values using a service, but when I tried to click submit button I got no value for the controls.

**edit-post.component.html:**

```
<form id='mainForm' [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitContent()" >
<select id="optCategory" formControlName="category">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option *ngFor="let Category of categoryArray" [value]="Category.id">{{Category.postCategory}}</option>
</select>

<input type="text" placeholder="Post Subject" id="txtSubject" formControlName="txtSubject">



<input type="text" id="txtTags" name="Tags" formControlName="txtTags" placeholder="Tags">
<button id="btn" type="submit" >Submit</button>

</form>
```

**edit-post.component.ts:**

```
//Properties Section: 
  postDetails: Post;
  _returnedURL= '';
  isReadOnly= false;
  categoryArray= [];
  form;
     constructor(
        private _CategoriesService: GetCategoriesService, fb: FormBuilder) {
          this.isReadOnly = false;
         this.form = fb.group({
          txtTags: [''],
          category: [''],
          txtSubject: ['']
        });
     }



  ngOnInit() {
this._CategoriesService.GetCategoriesService().subscribe(function(resp){
  this.categoryArray = resp;
}.bind(this));

    this.storePostDetails();
  }


  storePostDetails() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.getPostDetails.GetPostDetailsService(this.PostId).subscribe( resp => {
  this.postDetails = resp;
  this.title = this.postDetails.editorContent;

      });
    });
  }

  submitContent() {   
    console.log('Subject: ' + this.form.get('txtSubject').value);
    console.log('Tags: ' + this.form.get('txtTags').value);
    console.log('Editor: ' + this.form.get('editorContent').value);
}
```

When the page loads all the controls get populated with values, but when I hit submit button no value appears in the console.

Comment: What happens when you add `novalidate` to your `#mainForm` element? And I'm pretty sure you have to use `new` with `formBuilder`.

Comment: @Pytth no difference, i tried to add novalidate to the form element, why i should use new with formBuilder?